# Using angular 2 http offline when loading JSON in local project folder

Tags: javascript, json, angular, http

I have been trying loading a local json file present in my project folder of Angular 2 using http get method. Look at the following example code snippet:

```
private _productURL = 'api/products/products.json';    
getProducts(): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.get(this._productURL).map((response : Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
        .do(data =>console.log(JSON.stringify(data))).catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Now when I'm trying to load it with internet connected, it's working. But when I'm turing on the offline checkbox from the browser developer options(https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#offline), the json stops loading again. It starts showing me error in console about No internet connection and doesn't load anything.

Is there any other way to do this? or using http get..how to do it?

Comment: do you want to load it from a json var if there is no connection or that you want to store a copy once you have a connection and load it if there is no connection?

Comment: I have a long json array stored in a seprate file which will not change..i.e. it will be static..so it will go as a part of my project

Comment: so why load it using http?

Comment: I searched on internet.. This is what I got.. What is the other way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can import a `json` file if you do as follows:

create a json-typings.d.ts file with:

```js
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

this is a [wildcard module definition](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) that allows us to import non javascript files in this case JSON files.

you should now be able to import json files to your project:

```
import * as products from "./products.json";
```

Comment: Thank you..It's working!
Later I also tried using node.js require('./products.json') method to import it to a variable and then using it.
Was this method correct?

Comment: Okay.. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: how will this file get parsed , i mean we have to import this somewhere

Comment: in typescript there is no need to parse json

Comment: I just ran into this situation. Yes i went into this post [Reading local Json File](https://medium.com/@kgrvr/reading-local-json-present-in-an-angular-2-project-733bc3dda18e), and also [Modules explanation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) in typescript. But still didn't got into clear idea, like where i need to inject this newly created **json-typings.d.ts** , I want to apply this feature in ionic 3 Angular 4 app. If any one can help me like where i need to place this module and how to use this in providers inside ionic 3 app ?

Comment: I need to read local json in angular 4/5 and not sure where do I put the json-typings.d.ts and products.json. I've added my local json file under assets folder and json-typings.d.ts under "src" folder and imporrted the json in my angular root app component. However, I don't see the properties of my json object. Where do I need to place these files?

Comment: json-typings.d.ts must be placed on the same level as index.html or main.ts file. That is src folder if you created your project via Angular CLI. @hari

Comment: @jyoti-prasad-pal
Properties will not be visible in vs code intellisense.These will be available to you in runtime. You need to import that json via relative route.

Comment: @KushGrover, you've said "json-typings.d.ts" must be placed on the same level as index.html or main.ts file. Do I need to put my "products.json" on the same level or I can place it under src\assets folder?

Comment: @jyoti-prasad-pal  You can place json file anywhere in your src folder.

Comment: hi Iam getting module not found error while importing json .Can u pls provide a sample code or help me to fix it