# Use external JSON file's value while defining NgModule

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently I'm using a quite common solution to load a JSON file's content into my Angular 5 application that I can inject into my components. This works like it's described here under section [Runtime configuration](https://juristr.com/blog/2018/01/ng-app-runtime-config/#runtime-configuration).

I'm using an npm package which needs to be initialized in my app.module.ts file

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        /* .... */
        [MsalModule.forRoot({
            clientID: "...",
            authority: "...",
            redirectUri: <I need the value here from the JSON file>
        })]
    ],
    providers: [
        ConfigService,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => () => config.load(),
            deps: [ConfigService],
            multi: true
        }
    ]
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I use Angular-CLI and I know that I could use different environment files, but the content of the JSON file might change after building the application and I cannot rely on that.

Is there a way to use a value from the JSON file immediately in the NgModule declaration, where I need it?

Comment: window.location.origin would be perfect instead of reading the data from the JSON file, but that solution only works locally, for some really strange reason. As soon as I deploy my app to Azure and try to load it, it will be instantiated with a 'null' value, although console.log(window.location.origin) shows me the correct URL that I would need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good alternative can be found [here
in this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43345347/using-angular-2-http-offline-when-loading-json-in-local-project-folder/43365447#43365447)

This way to JSON file can be loaded as a JS object and we can access it before declaring the NgModule.

Answer (score 1):

This way to JSON file can be loaded and we can access it before declaring the NgModule.

**Json File:**

```
{
    "apiUrl":"http://localhost:52361/"
}
```

**Module File:**

```
import Configuration from '../assets/config.json'; 

GridModule.forRoot(Configuration.apiUrl)
```